# Vue3: How can I use props in component setup?

Tags: vue.js

Props wont work in compontent.

My View looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col text-center">
  {{ checklist.nextchecklistId }}
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg font-monospace fs-2" @click="jumpToNextChecklist"><NextChecklist :nextChecklist="checklist.nextchecklistId" /></button>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
import NextChecklist from '@/components/NextChecklist.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    NextChecklist,
  },
}
</script>
```

The Component looks like:

```
<template>
    <span>ghj</span>
</template>
    
<script>
    export default {
        name: "NextChecklist",
        props: [
            'nextChecklist'
        ],
        setup(props) {
                console.log(props.nextChecklist);
        },
    };
</script>
```

**props.nextChecklist** is undefined in component. In View I added a simple output **{{ checklist.nextchecklistId }}** this works fine and the correct value will shown, but not in Component.

Comment: How do you update `checklist.nextchecklistId` in parent component?

Comment: if you want script setup, you can use like **[this](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits)** your props in vue3

Comment: You haven't shown any definition for `checklist` in the parent, so we have no [mre] to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `nextChecklist` prop is not being passed correctly to your `NextChecklist` component. Let's make sure that the prop is properly passed from the parent component to the child component.

In your parent component's template, you should use the `v-bind` directive (or its shorthand `:`) to bind the value of `checklist.nextchecklistId` to the `nextChecklist` prop:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col text-center">
    {{ checklist.nextchecklistId }}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg font-monospace fs-2" @click="jumpToNextChecklist">
      <NextChecklist :nextChecklist="checklist.nextchecklistId" />
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your `NextChecklist` component, you can access the `nextChecklist` prop through the `props` object:

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "NextChecklist",
  props: {
    nextChecklist: String, // Define the prop type if it's a string
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.nextChecklist); // This should now log the value
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

checklist.nextchecklistId is create by request?

if yes, please use watch props in component

```js
 watch(props.nextChecklist, (newValue) => {
      console.log(newValue);
    });
```